# More details about CRM error : "Solution manifest import: FAILURE"

Tags: c#, import, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am creating an import / export tool for CRM using C#.
Sometimes, I am facing to an import error, with only this message "Solution manifest import: FAILURE" in my catch. I tried to cast it to its type (FaultException), but I haven't any more details.

If I do the import of the same file directly in CRM, I have a better error message (this one for exemple : "Import of solution xxxx failed. The following components are missing in yout system [...]").

Is there a way to get this complete message ?

Here is my code :

```
try
{
    _serviceProxy.Execute(impSolReq);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault>)
        MessageBox.Show("Error during import. More details: " + ((FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault>)ex).Detail);
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Error during import. More details: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamics CRM solutions are imported using the `ImportSolutionRequest`.

The `ImportSolutionRequest` has a property containing the ID of the solution import job. You need this ID to be able to monitor the progress of the job and to get error details when the import fails.

Instantiation of the request could look like this:

```
Guid importJobId = Guid.NewGuid();

var request = new ImportSolutionRequest
{
    ConvertToManaged = true,
    CustomizationFile = buffer, // a byte[] array holding the solution contents
    ImportJobId = importJobId,
    OverwriteUnmanagedCustomizations = true,
    PublishWorkflows = true,
    SkipProductUpdateDependencies = false
};
```

Execute the request. When an import error occurs, you can retrieve the error details using the job id.

```
try
{
    _service.Execute(request);
}
catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
{
    if (ex.Detail.ErrorCode == -2147188685) // ImportSolutionError
    {
        Entity job = _service.Retrieve("importjob", importJobId, new ColumnSet { AllColumns = true });
        // TODO: process job error details.
    }

    throw;
}
```

Attribute `importjob.data` contains an XML document with the details you are looking for.

The `ImportSolutionRequest` is executed synchronously and can easily time-out. Time-outs however can safely be ignored, because the import process continues to run in the background. You can track progress by retrieving the import job record at regular intervals. As long as attribute `importjob.completedon` is `null`, the job is still running.

Comment: With CRM 2011 solution can be only imported synchronously and starting from CRM 2013 they can also be imported asynchronously. Your code is synchronous.

Comment: You're right. I got this code from a tool I created for CRM 2011 last year. Eventually the `ImportSolutionRequest` times out, but this exception can be ignored and progress can still be monitored by retrieving the import job at regular intervals. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! I used already the jobId to display a progress bar, but I didn't pay attention about the xml data that contains a better error message.